# incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file which has two columns: Symbol and TP
There are 2 different Symbols in Symbol: 'AAPL' and 'GOOG', what I want to do it I want to add a extra column to store the 14 days average TP groupby the Symbol. i.e. the average TP is only calculated with in the same Symbol,(so there will be 14*2 rows are NaN in average TP column). Here is what I have done:

```
TP = pd.read_csv('TP.csv', index_col= False)
#copy the data frame
meanTP_14 = TP[['Symbol', 'TP']].copy()
#calculation of mean and std
mean_14 = meanTP_14.groupby('Symbol')['TP'].rolling(window = 14).mean()
std_14 = meanTP_14.groupby('Symbol')['TP'].rolling(window = 14).std()
# return mean_14 back to the dataframe
meanTP_14['mean_14'] = mean_14
```

then I run into this error: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index, what can I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is with `MultiIndex`, you can remove first level by:

```
meanTP_14['mean_14'] = mean_14.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```